# Склонение названия города. Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: склонение

Как пишется правильно: Исследования в городе Пятигорск**е** или исследование в городе Пятигорск? И еще исследование потребителей города Пятигорск или города Пятигорска? Помогите) Срочно нужно) Спасибо 3аранее)

Answer (score 2):

В городе Пятигорске, города Пятигорска. Географические названия - имена сущ. ед. числа со словом ГОРОД склоняются всегда.